# Access plugin controller from js

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, plugins

I want to create a plugin. In my plugin I must call controller action from my function. Below is the snippet of ajax call, which is in separate js file.

```
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"/wf-taglibs/refTagLib/getDescriptionByCode",
            data:{
                'code':code,
                'beanClass':beanClassAttribute
            },

            success:function (data) {
                $('#' + updateFieldAttribute).text(data);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
```

I've got problem with url. url:"/wf-taglibs/refTagLib/getDescriptionByCode", As response we get 'the requested page not found'.

Comment: Where is your controller entry point? i.e: http://yoursite.com/wf-taglibs/refTagLib/getDescriptionByCode

Comment: I tried it, seems it does not work.

Comment: as @MartinBorthiry said, you need to specify **the full path** of the service, including "http:\\"

Comment: Try specifying the file type : /wf-taglibs/refTagLib/getDescriptionByCode(.php)?

Comment: Sorry, but my question was what is the right url for your controller?

Comment: my application url is http://localhost:8080/myApp. wf-taglibs is a plugin which is included to myApp. The problem is that I cannot access to the controller of my wf-taglibs plugin.

Comment: @emilan if your app urls starts with `/myApp`, why you're trying to use different url?

Comment: Because both my js and controller action are in plugin.

Comment: `refTagLib` is your controller that exists in the plugin? Try to call without the `wf-taglibs`. If this not work, you can play with [url mappings](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#urlmappings) to map your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't hard code URLs like this, but rather declare a js variable inside of my gsp that points to the right controller/action and then have my js code use that variable.

```
var getDescriptionEndpoint = "${createLink(controller:'x', action:'x')}";
```

And then use that variable in the js code that makes ajax calls.
That way it will consider reverse url mappings as well.

Though its not a good idea, but if you want to declare your variables directly into js file - in otherwords - if you want to treat your js files as gsp - see gsp-arse plugin

Comment: This returns string and doesn't work for separate .js file. This works only when it is in .gsp file.

Comment: Yes, you are right.. I would have a gsp file that holds such type of variable declarations and then I would include that gsp file inside <script> tag wherever I need them, you can have more then one such gspfiles to group variables accordingly.

Comment: Though its not a good idea, but if you want to declare your variables directly into js file - in otherwords - if you want to treat your js files as gsp - see gsp-arse plugin